# Is 我五分钟后就回来 ambiguous out of context?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

My newsletter says this sentence

> 我五分钟后就回来。

is translated as "I'll be back in 5 minutes".

I am curious to know whether this sentence could be translated as "I came back 5 minutes ago", or does it need to be changed? If so, how and why?

Comment: Did you mean to ask if it could also be "I came back 5 minutes later."? That would be a more interesting question.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: I did not, but it is an interesting question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"I'll be back in 5 minutes" is the only correct translation for this sentence.

"I came back 5 minutes ago" is

> 我5分钟前就回来了。

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but I think "in 5 minutes" here doesn't mean "5分钟后". For example, now it's 00:12.

When I say "I will be back in 5 minutes", I mean "I will have come back by 00:17. I probably come back at 00:13, or 00:14". In this case, I will say, in Chinese, "我5分钟内回来“。

When I say "I will be back 5 minutes later". I mean "I will be back at 00:17,". In this case, I will say, in Chinese, "我5分钟后回来“。

Please correct me if I misunderstand "in 5 minutes" and "5 minutes later".

Comment: Your understanding is perfect!

Comment: I don't agree. If I say "I'll be back in 5 minutes" at 00:12, I'm saying I'll be back at 00:17.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete, strictly speaking, "in" means [within](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in?s=t) a certain time period, but usage wise I tend to agree with you.

Comment: I'm just saying that that is how I use it. I can't tell you how other English speakers interpret it, but for me, it's definitely `过X分钟之后`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this sentence should be translated as "I will be back after 5 mins"

"I'll be back in 5 minutes" should be

> 我在五分钟内回来

Comment: I don't agree. If I say "I'll be back in 5 minutes" at 00:12, I'm saying I'll be back at 00:17.

Comment: I think the latter should be "I'll be back *within* five minutes."

Answer (score 1):

My take:-

(a)  我五分钟后就回来 --- I'll be back in 5 minutes.

The "后" here does not mean "after" 5 minutes, but after whatever time I left the place.

(b)  我在五分钟之内就回来 ---   I'll be back within 5 minutes.

"在...之内", generally to denote "within".

(c)  我五分钟过后就回来   ---   I'll be back after 5 minutes.

The "过后" denotes passing "beyond" the event.